# Looking for an openGL 2.1 cheat sheet

Tags: opengl

Looking at the opengl website they have cheat sheets for modern openGL but not for 2.1, I tried to find them on the wayback machine but it seems like they either never made them or I just can't find them.

Does anyone know where I can find an openGL 2.1 cheat sheet?

Answer (score 2):

There never were any of these back then. The only quick reference that was around was [the one for GLSL](http://mew.cx/glsl_quickref.pdf)